# Excel Search Two Columns With Two Conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to search a date and a value (name) and the return the first value of the first entry and past it to another worksheet, and then a second value on the last entry for another cell in the same worksheet.

As you can see in the images, I think is easier to understand.

Result:

[image: Result.]

Table to look:

[image: Table to look.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This method solves the issue:*

[image]

- Array (CSE) formula in Cell `D28`:

  ```
  {=MIN(IF(($A$18:$A$25=$A28)*($B$18:$B$25=$B28),$D$18:$D$25))}
  ```
- Array (CSE) formula in Cell `E28`:

  ```
  {=MAX(IF(($A$18:$A$25=$A28)*($B$18:$B$25=$B28),$E$18:$E$25))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish both formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

---

**Edited:**

*Below shown method is been included since OP is suppose to get `Login & Logout time` using multiple criteria (`Date, Driver 1 & Driver 2`) also.*

[image]

- An array (CSE) formula in `D29`:

  ```
  {=MIN(IF($A$18:$A$25=$A29,IF($B$18:$B$25=$B29,IF($C$18:$C$25=$C29,$D$18:$D$25))))}
  ```
- An array (CSE) formula in `E29`:

  ```
  {=MAX(IF($A$18:$A$25=$A29, IF($B$18:$B$25=$B29,IF($C$18:$C$25=$C29,$E$18:$E$25))))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Alter Date, Driver's name as needed.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thank you a lot. It works but it works only in the first column (Driver 1). 

What I want is all the ocurrences of Driver 1 and Driver 2 columns. Can I extend the search?

For example:

{=MIN(IF(($A$18:$A$25=$A28)*($B$18:$C$25=$B28),$D$18:$D$25))}

Thank you a lot for your help. Kind regards.

Comment: I've figured it out. I can put do it with:
{=MIN(IF(($A$18:$A$25=$A28)*(OR($B$18:$B$25=$B28,$C$18:$C$25=$B28)),$D$18:$D$25))}

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a problem... when I change the name, the values do not update.

Comment: @Focha,, glad to help you,, what you are trying may not work sometimes since with `Driver 1 & 2` the `Date` is a criteria also,,  and `login time` works with `MIN` function so it will consider `Date + Value in cell B28` any odd combination will return unexpected result or even error !!

Comment: @Focha,, now check the post, I've shown how to use both Driver's name for Date to get Login and logout time.

Comment: thank you. I think it solved. I will try. Kind regards.

Comment: @Focha  glad to help U,, keep asking ☺